# Why does a new audio file start playing if one is already playing? (JS)

Tags: javascript, if-statement, audio, playback

I don't know why, but I can't figure out why this does not work. I've been sitting for hours trying different methods, reading and watching videos on the subject, but I still can not figure it out.

**Q:** Why does a "new" audio file start playing, overlapping the previous one, every time I click the element? Should my if statement not take care of that?

```
document.getElementById("chatWrapper").addEventListener("click", playSound);

function playSound() {
    //alert("Success!");
    var sEE0 = new Audio('../sound/00-menu-music.mp3');
        sEE0.volume = 0.2;
    if (sEE0.duration > 0) {

        return;
    } else {
        sEE0.play();
    }
}
```

How do I solve this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be creating a new audio element each time you click.

Try to initialize it only once: (attn, quick'n'dirty!)

```
document.getElementById("chatWrapper").addEventListener("click", playSound);
var sEE0 = new Audio('../sound/00-menu-music.mp3');
function playSound() {
    //alert("Success!");
    sEE0.volume = 0.2;
    if (sEE0.duration > 0) {
        return;
    } else {
        sEE0.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: "You seem to be creating a new audio element each time you click."

I was actually thinking about that, but it is still the same variable, isn't it? So like it should not matter.

I also tried your example earlier, but doing so, it does not even play at all.

Comment: Think its the "new Audio" part, not the variable per se. Why it does not work - I do not know without a more complete example, so that's the reason I said "quick'n'dirty"

Comment: Okey. I don't know how it could be more "complete"? The "chatWrapper" is just a simple div on the page.

Comment: Here is basically what it is as a full.

    `<body>
        <div id="chatWrapper"></div>  
        <script>
            document.getElementById("chatWrapper").addEventListener("click", playSound);

            function playSound() {
                //alert("Success!");
                var sEE0 = new Audio('sound/00-menu-music.mp3');
                    sEE0.volume = 0.2;
                if (sEE0.duration > 0) {

                    return;
                } else {
                    sEE0.play();
                }
            } 
        </script>
    </body>`

Answer (score 0):

like @frontend_dev said, one of your problem is the variable scoping, other is you are checking using `sEE0.duration`, but that would give you the length of the audio file, which is bound to be bigger than `0`, may be that's why it is not playing, what you are looking for is `currentTime`, the if condition should be `if (sEE0.duration > 0) {` ,

but I would prefer checking if the audio is playing or paused, rather than checking till what part the audio has played( unless the usecase requires that)

I would re-write the code as:

```
document.getElementById("chatWrapper").addEventListener("click", playSound);
var sEE0 = new Audio('../sound/00-menu-music.mp3');
sEE0.volume = 0.2;
function playSound() {
    //alert("Success!");
    if (sEE0.paused) {
        sEE0.play();
    }
}
```